# how to get checkbox list unchecked item

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

i have a datalist contains checkboxlist.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dtlstfilter" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBoxList ForeColor="Gray"  AutoPostBack="true"    OnSelectedIndexChanged="chklist_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="chklist"
 runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

when i check one from the checkbox list in the SelectedIndexChanged event i got the selected value using

```
CheckBoxList c = (CheckBoxList)sender;
string selectedvalue= c.SelectedValue;
```

likewise how can get the value from a checkboxlist if i uncheck one from the checkboxlist

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedIndexChanged` gets also fired if you uncheck a `CheckBox`. So it works the same way. But if you want to know the (now) unchecked item(s), you have to store the old selection somewhere, for example in the `ViewState`:

```
private IEnumerable<string> SelectedValues
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["SelectedValues"] == null && dtlstfilter.SelectedIndex >= -1)
        {
            ViewState["SelectedValues"] = dtlstfilter.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                .Where(li => li.Selected)
                .Select(li => li.Value)
                .ToList();
        }else
            ViewState["SelectedValues"]  = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        return (IEnumerable<string>)ViewState["SelectedValues"];
    }
    set { ViewState["SelectedValues"] = value; }
}

protected void chklist_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList c = (CheckBoxList)sender;
    var oldSelection = this.SelectedValues;
    var newSelection = c.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                .Where(li => li.Selected)
                .Select(li => li.Value);
    var uncheckedItems = newSelection.Except(oldSelection);
}
```

This should even work if multiple checkboxes can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the jQuery Route if it suits you...

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in chkList.Items)
    {
        //adding a dummy class to use at client side.
        item.Attributes.Add("class", "chkItem");
    }
}
```

Put one button on your form with style display : none. And a Hidden Field to track the currently checked checkbox.

```
<asp:Button ID="hdnButton" runat="server" style="display:none;" OnClick="hdnButton_Click"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrent" runat="server" />
```

The jQuery Part....

```
$(".chkItem input:checkbox").change(function(){            
    $("#hdnCurrent").val($(this).attr("id") + "|" + $(this).attr("checked"));
    $("#hdnButton").click();
});
```

You can use more hidden fields if you don't want to do string operations on backend. Depends on your taste.

Then handle the button click event like below.

```
protected void hdnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] Value = hdnCurrent.Value.Split('|');

    if (Value[1] == "true")
    {
        //Do operations here when the check box is checked
    }
    else
    { 
        //Do operations here when the check box is unchecked
    }

    //Value[0] contains the id of the check box that is checked/unchecked.
}
```